# Sitecore Advanced Database Crawler and Partial Language Falback

Tags: lucene, sitecore, culture

We have ADC and Partial Language Fallback both implemented in our Sitecore installs. We have identified an issue which we are hoping somebody else has come across and can help us in resolving this issue.

Basically, when a non-default (Chinese for example) language item version is created after the default language (global English) version and the Chinese version "falls back" on the English version, Lucene crawler doesn't pick up the non-default versions. When the "fall back" is broken by modifying the Chinese version, Lucene picks up the item.

I am wondering if there is a solution or hint on where to look at next to try to fix this.

Thanks

Comment: Are different languages stored in separate indexes?

Comment: Hows your ADC Viewer looks like?

Comment: There is one index for all languages.

Comment: Gunda - What is ADC Viewer?

Comment: Use Shared Source module called "Index Viewer" and you'll likely find the cause of the issue.

Comment: I've used that and Luke to debug the issue but the problem happens before indexing.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an older post, but we have an answer to this and a fix, and you can find the answers in detail in the sitecore technology blogs here:

http://www.sitecore.net/Community/Technical-Blogs/Elizabeth-Spranzani/Posts/2014/03/Fallback-Series-Post-6.aspx

I have a 10 post series about language fallback up here.

The reason is because when the adc crawler goes through the items and puts the values of each field into the index, it does not know about language fallback and does not use it.  So it sees the value as null.  You need to add to the logic so that it applies fallback, looks at the fallback language version of the field, and then puts that value into the index instead.

You can also find code to download here:
https://github.com/Verndale-Corp/Sitecore-Fallback-ADC-Updates

Thanks,
Liz